# RxJS: How can I suppress identical events that occur within a certain time period?

Tags: rxjs

I have duplicate events that I want to ignore, but only if they occur within a given time period. If the same event occurs, but it is outside the time period, that should not be ignored.

My first thought is some combination of `throttle` and `distinctUntilChanged`

```
// Does not work because if two different events occur within the time period, I want to process them both
event$.pipe(
  throttleTime(300)
).subscribe((event) => console.log(event));

// Does not work because if the same event occur two minutes apart, I want to process them both
event$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((previous, current) => JSON.stringify(previous) === JSON.stringify(current))
).subscribe((event) => console.log(event));
```

Can anyone suggest a way to combine these or something else to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks to [@maxime1992 for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919867/600528). It worked perfectly. Here is a resulable operator I created based on his answer.

```
/**
 * RxJS operator that throttles groups of events to prevent the grouped event from emitting more then once within a given time period
 * By default events are grouped based on the JSON.stringify value so JSON.stringify(event1) === JSON.stringify(event2)
 * will suppress event2 if they are identical
 *
 * @param duration - the time period in milliseconds in which to group events [default: 100]
 * @param keySelector - function that returns a string which defines the grouping [default: JSON.stringified(event)]
 * @returns - function used in an RxJs pipe
 *
 * example:
 * import { throttleGroups } from "rxjs-utils"
 *
 * // throttle events with the same url property
 * rapidEvents$.pipe(
 *      throttleGroups(500, (event) => event.url)
 * ).subscribe((event) => console.log('never see the same url within 500ms', event.url));
 *
 * // throttle events that are completely identical
 * rapidEvents$.pipe(
 *      throttleGroups()
 * ).subscribe((event) => console.log('never see the same event within 100ms', event));
 */
export const throttleGroups = (duration: number = 100, keySelector = (event): string => JSON.stringify(event)) => {
    return function<T> (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
        return source.pipe(
            groupBy(keySelector),
            mergeMap((eventGroup$) => eventGroup$.pipe(throttleTime(duration)))
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [groupBy](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/groupBy) comes in really handy for this:

```js
event$
  .pipe(
    groupBy((event) => JSON.stringify(event)),
    mergeMap((eventGroup$) =>
      eventGroup$.pipe(
        throttleTime(500, undefined, {
          leading: true,
          trailing: false,
        })
      )
    )
  )
```

Here's a [live demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vuxzvp?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

If we define `event$` as

```js
const event$ = from([
  { eventId: 1 },
  { eventId: 2 },
  { eventId: 3 },
  { eventId: 1 },
  { eventId: 1 },
  { eventId: 3 },
]);
```

The output is:

```
{eventId: 1}
{eventId: 2}
{eventId: 3}
```

Feel free to tweak the `leading` and `trailing` based on what you need.

Comment: groupBy and mergeMap: I think this is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the humans... I also asked ChatGPT this question and it repeatedly and confidently gave me wrong answers. LOL!

Comment: Haha glad I passed the Turing test :)